# Facebook SDK 3 Login Button Identify on click

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` component to log into Facebook:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    stat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    //authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status",
            "user_status", "user_events", "friends_events"));

    return view;
}
```

I want to prompt the user his login status, so I need to change a text view when Facebook's button was pressed.

But I can't seem to find a way to identify user's click, without changing Facebook's lib, or override `LoginButton` native listener.

Comment: Read sharedpref if your loginin setbuttonpressed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've run into the same problem while trying to implement a login lib for my application. So far the solution I found, still not sure whether it is the best or not, was changing *LoginClickListener* Class inside facebook-sdk from *private* to *public*, so I could override the *onClick* method on my Activity. Here is the line I've changed.

From:

```
private class LoginClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
```

To:

```
public class LoginClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
```

Then on my Activity I'm able to Override onClick method.

```
LoginButton facebookButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
facebookButton.setOnClickListener( facebookButton.new LoginClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do whatever u want
        super.onClick(v);
    }
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: It's exactly what I need, but I get error, something at AppEventsLogger.java file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the `HelloFacebookSample`. They are doing something like this there.

```
loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
        updateUI(user);
    }
});
```

then in `updateUI()` method

```
private void updateUI(GraphUser user) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened() && user != null) {
        mTextView.setText(user.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

If you are taking care about the connection session(see the sample for details), then the user login status will be kept even when he exit the app.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to override the `onclick` method or changing Facebook's lib. you can use the `SessionState` to detect if the `loginButton` has been clicked. When the `SessionState` is OPENING it means that the button has been clicked

```
private Session.StatusCallback fBcallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        Session fbSession = session;

        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "fbSession isNULL "
                + (fbSession == null));

        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(),
                "fbSession state:" + fbSession.getState() + "");

        switch (fbSession.getState()) {
        case CLOSED:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "CLOSED");

            break;
        case CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "CLOSED LOGIN FAILED");

            authButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case CREATED:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "CREATED");

            break;
        case CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "CREATED TOKEN LOADED");

            break;
        case OPENED:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "OPENED");

            break;
        case OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "OPENED TOKEN UPDATED");

            break;
        case OPENING:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "OPENING");

            authButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }

        if (fbSession.isOpened()) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "fbSession is opened");

            getFBUserData();
        }
        if (fbSession.isClosed()) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "fbSession is closed, logout");
            Token.removeToken(mActivity);
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of overloading the LoginButton, I just used the image background.  While the text does not align perfectly by default, playing with the margins can help.

```
Button fbBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fbLogin) ;
if( fbBtn != null )
{
    fbBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.com_facebook_loginbutton_blue) ) ;
    fbBtn.setText( R.string.prompt_login_yes ) ;
    fbBtn.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_loginview_text_color) ) ;
    fbBtn.setTextSize( 16 ) ;
    fbBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
}
```